# CUA mode is implictly cutting and copying from region

Tags: cua-mode

I'm confused about some CUA mode implicit behaviour that I got after upgrading Emacs, specifically:

- Marking a region automatically copies it, without having to type `C-c`
- Deleting a region automatically kills it, without having to type `C-x`

I find this confusing because I often want to kill a region with `C-x`, do a backspace on a second region to delete it and then paste with `C-v` to replace with the original region.

I find however that once I delete the second region, it replaces the first one in the kill ring and I get it pasted right back again after `C-v`.

**EDIT:** Here's an example of what is currently happening. Suppose I have a buffer with these two lines

```
This number is 1
This number is 2
```

I want to swap the characters 1 and 2 between the two lines. I try to take these steps:

Put a region around '1' and cut it with `C-x`. The character duly disappears:

```
This number is 
This number is 2
```

Put a region around '2' and type backspace to delete:

```
This number is
This number is
```

Put the cursor at the end of the second line and type `C-v` in the hope that it will paste the '1' character. What I get instead is:

```
This number is
This number is 2
```

So, deleting the region around '2' implicitly put it in the kill ring, as if I had typed `C-x`.

A similar thing happens just by setting the region, which CUA is implicitly copying as if I had typed `C-c`. If I then move the cursor somewhere else and type `C-v`, I get the region pasted back.

Is this normal behaviour? I would prefer to do the cutting and copying explicitly, without CUA doing it behind my back.

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you please edit your post to clarify what your question is?

Comment: What @Dan said. Consider providing a step-by-step recipe, which shows what happens, and say what you expected/wanted to happen instead.

Comment: When you need to clarify a post, please edit the original question rather than post an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found the culprit. I had this customisation in my `.emacs` that I had forgotten about:

```
(select-enable-primary t)
```

I don't understand how this would interfere with CUA but I removed this customisation without any observable adverse effects so far.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see what you report, when starting Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file).

Do you? If not, then recursively bisect your init file to find out what part of it is interfering. You can comment out a region of text using command `comment-region`. Comment out 1/2, then 3/4, 7/8,... until you locate the problem.

(A step-by-step recipe to reproduce a problem should include anything you've done to modify the default Emacs behavior, i.e., what you get using only `emacs -Q`.)